# Calling UserManager.AddToRole erases user password?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I am fairly new to MVC5/ASP.NET Identity and I have found an issue that has stumped me a bit.

I am writing a small form for my ASP.NET MVC5 application that will allow an admin user (member of the Admins role) to review the users that have signed up to the site and edit the details of and assign roles to those users. When the form is submitted, if a role has been assigned to the user the UserManager.AddToRole method is called.

I noticed after this that once this is done, that user is then unable to log into the application. Looking in the database, it appears when AddToRole is called, the PasswordHash field is set to null. Is this normal and if not how to I get around this issue?

For reference my relevant code is below

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Details(EditUserViewModel model)
{
    model.Save();

    return RedirectToAction("List", "Account");
}
```

Relevant view models

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<EditUserRolesViewModel> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Id = this.UserId,
                UserName = this.UserName,
                Email = this.Email,
                FirstName = this.FirstName,
                LastName = this.LastName,
                MobileNumber = this.MobileNumber
            };

            context.Users.Attach(user);
            context.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Email).IsModified = true;
            context.Entry(user).Property(x => x.FirstName).IsModified = true;
            context.Entry(user).Property(x => x.LastName).IsModified = true;
            context.Entry(user).Property(x => x.MobileNumber).IsModified = true;
            context.SaveChanges();

            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            foreach (var row in this.UserRoles)
            {
                if (row.RowChanged)
                {
                    if (row.RoleAssigned)
                    {
                        UserManager.AddToRole(this.UserId, row.RoleName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UserManager.RemoveFromRole(this.UserId, row.RoleName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class EditUserRolesViewModel
{
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Role name")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Assigned")]
    public bool RoleAssigned { get; set; }
    public bool RowChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As nsb mentions, the problem has nothing to do with AddToRoles.  The problem is actually at your context.SaveChanges() method.  It saves a partially initialized user over the existing user.

Comment: I checked the database after the first SaveChanges and the field hadn't been nulled at that point. I presume that using the same context for AddToRole was where that partially initialized user got saved over the existing one. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see from your code, you have attached partially initialized object `user` to `context.Users`. As a result when `UserManager` gets control: `AddToRole`, it tries to update Database. And you'll have lot empty or null fields in the current users row.

You can fix doing any of the following (both will help):

1. instead of 
   `ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()`
    use
    `user = UserManager.FindById(UserId)`
   after assigning values from viewmodel EntityFramework will take care of modified fields.
2. use another context when dealing with roles

   `var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));`

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thank you very much. I was using the IsModified of each property to specify which fields I wanted to save in the first part, I didn't twig that another save might occur when adding roles using that same context. Thanks again.